# Using webpack in my application and can't use javascript's typeof directive

Tags: javascript, function, webpack, typeof

So everytime I try to use typeof, like on the example below

```
window.clone = function clone(obj){
    if(obj === null || (typeof obj) !== 'object')
        return obj;

    var temp = new obj.constructor(); 
    for(var key in obj)
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);

    return temp;
};
```

It throws me this error

> Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof'

That's pretty ridiculous. What can I do in this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick Google returns a relevant issue reported in babel Github: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/39. If it doesn't help you, you might need to provide your webpack version and babel version to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install --save-dev @babel/runtime` worked for me :)

Sources:

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7514

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-runtime